# Preflight OPTIONS request with Faraday gem

Tags: ruby, faraday, preflight

How would I make a preflight request with [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday)? It seems there is a name collision.

```
# Create a connection
conn = Faraday.new('http://example.com')

# GET request
conn.get # => #<Faraday::Response

# POST request
conn.post # => #<Faraday::Response

# OPTIONS request collides?
conn.options # => #<struct Faraday::RequestOptions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As one [might see](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/e10ef5ea8952b7b848e797e2f80136426063d6b8/lib/faraday/connection.rb#L137-L180), the syntactic sugar is provided for all [methods](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/e10ef5ea8952b7b848e797e2f80136426063d6b8/lib/faraday/connection.rb#L15), save for `:options`. To perform such a request, one might call the wrapped [`Connection#run_request`](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/e10ef5ea8952b7b848e797e2f80136426063d6b8/lib/faraday/connection.rb#L365-L378) directly:

```
conn.run_request(:options, nil, nil, nil)
```